# No module named gps_goal

Tags: ros, gps

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Cloned gps_goal into my catkin workspace, catkin_make didn't return any error. When running the following command, it returns an importerror

```
 yuxiang@yuxiang:~/catkin_ws2$ roslaunch gps_goal gps_goal.launch
... logging to /home/yuxiang/.ros/log/434b3910-0c46-11ed-881b-3f02c6700c9f/roslaunch-yuxiang-445884.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take a while.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

started roslaunch server http://yuxiang:38821/

SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
 * /gps_goal/frame_id: map
 * /rosdistro: noetic
 * /rosversion: 1.15.14

NODES
  /
    gps_goal (gps_goal/gps_goal)

auto-starting new master
process[master]: started with pid [445899]
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

setting /run_id to 434b3910-0c46-11ed-881b-3f02c6700c9f
process[rosout-1]: started with pid [445916]
started core service [/rosout]
process[gps_goal-2]: started with pid [445919]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/yuxiang/catkin_ws2/src/gps_goal/nodes/gps_goal", line 3, in <module>
    from gps_goal import gps_goal
ImportError: No module named gps_goal
[gps_goal-2] process has died [pid 445919, exit code 1, cmd /home/yuxiang/catkin_ws2/src/gps_goal/nodes/gps_goal gps_goal_pose:=gps_goal_pose gps_goal_fix:=gps_goal_fix local_xy_origin:=local_xy_origin __name:=gps_goal __log:=/home/yuxiang/.ros/log/434b3910-0c46-11ed-881b-3f02c6700c9f/gps_goal-2.log].
log file: /home/yuxiang/.ros/log/434b3910-0c46-11ed-881b-3f02c6700c9f/gps_goal-2*.log
^C[rosout-1] killing on exit
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/404226/no-module-named-gps_goal/) by [noname](https://answers.ros.org/users/98100/noname/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2022-07-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Did you source (e.g. `source devel/setup.bash` in the `catkin_ws` folder) the workspace after `catkin_make`?

---

Originally posted by [ljaniec](https://answers.ros.org/users/63587/ljaniec/) with karma: 3064 on 2022-07-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [noname](https://answers.ros.org/users/98100/noname/) on 2022-07-26**:
Yes I did, unfortunately it still does not work

**Comment by [ljaniec](https://answers.ros.org/users/63587/ljaniec/) on 2022-07-27**:
Can you link this package so we can check how it works? Then I could check if it builds in my workspace. Is it [this one](https://wiki.ros.org/gps_goal)? It is for ROS Kinetic, there is no `ros-noetic-gps-goal` binary package as I checked. Remember that ROS Kinetic uses Python 2.7, not Python 3. You can try to rebuild it with deleting `install`, `log`, `build` folders, then `source devel/setup.bash` and check again. You can try to use not the launch file, but the [CLI with `python gps_goal.py`](https://github.com/danielsnider/gps_goal/blob/6cfdb24513fd603e803a809faac404cd52979c7c/src/gps_goal/gps_goal.py#L133)

**Comment by [noname](https://answers.ros.org/users/98100/noname/) on 2022-07-29**:
I noticed that the package has not been updated for a few years. Thanks for the help I will try `python gps_goal.py`

**Comment by [noname](https://answers.ros.org/users/98100/noname/) on 2022-08-13**:
It works, thank you boss

**Comment by [ljaniec](https://answers.ros.org/users/63587/ljaniec/) on 2022-08-14**:
If it worked, please accept it as an answer :)

**Comment by [noname](https://answers.ros.org/users/98100/noname/) on 2022-08-14**:
I thought I already did?

**Comment by [ljaniec](https://answers.ros.org/users/63587/ljaniec/) on 2022-08-15**:
You have a second button under the `<1>` with text "mark this answer as correct` - I thought about this one